# how to use java code from .net desktop application?

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, desktop-application, windows

I want to Use Some Java Code From the WCF Service. Basically I need to intreact with the java application from the .net so how can I make it out for that? Any guidance for that?

I was just wondering that how can i call java code from my .net desktop application? Do I need to create .exe file of my java poject or jar? How would I invoke that java project from my .net desktop application?

Like some code in .net desktopp application will call

```
void startprocessing ();
```

code written in java application

Let me Clear the Things What i want to implement..

I have one desktop appplication of windows and I want to integrate my speech recgnition facility in that application which is in java. What I want is to exchange the audio data as binary and some strings from .net application to my java application so I can process on that binary data to convert wav file and etc and recginze it..that is just completed ..but what I need to know is how to send those strings and some binary data to java application and just invoke that java application ?? Do I need to 'use'(?) wcf or other service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Successfully done that with the axis 2 webservice with tomcat apache server with the following link..its too easy .i really got succeeded

http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html

Answer (score 2):

Going out on a limb here, sounds like you java app needs to expose the method you want to call via a web-service. That's of course assuming you have control over that in terms of the java app you're interacting with. Not sure though you can access that method simply by compiling your java app to native.

Comment: let me explain now. i have one desktop appplication of windows and i want to integrate my speech recgnition facility in that application which is in java .what i want is to exchange the audio data as binary and some strings from .net application to my java application so i can process on that binary data to convert wav file and etc and recginze it..that is just completed ..but what ma need is how to send those strings and some binary data to java application and just invoke that java application ?? am i need to wcf or other service ?

Comment: ... communicating via web service would afford you a lot of flexibility. Another possibility would be to look into java and networking : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/overview/networking.html, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/), which provides interop possibilities between Java and .NET. However, as another poster has suggested, exposing the functionality through a web service is probably a better solution.

A quick Google search will give you plenty of information on how to create web services in Java, but for starters you can take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html